# Partially apply css image filter

Tags: css

What I'd like to do is partially apply a css filter to a background image with with background-size cover. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/vFYFz/

```
<div id="grandparent">
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="original">
</div>

#original {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://userserveak.last.fm/serve/_/96476693/Natural+Mystic+JPG.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

#grandparent {
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%; height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

#parent {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/96476693/Natural+Mystic+JPG.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-filter: invert(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
}
```

The filtered image needs to have the width of the viewport, in order to follow the same background-size cover as the original, so I've put it inside a fixed element with 100% width. I'd like it to obey the overflow of its grandparent absolute element, so that I can apply the filter to only the left 33% of the image, but this doesn't work. Any ideas how I might pull this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to switch the position of the "grandparent" and the "parent": [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vFYFz/1/)

```
#grandparent {
    position: fixed;
    width: 33%; height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

#parent {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually trying to get the filtered image to have the same proportions as the original image though. I.e. have a background image positioned with size cover where only the left 33% of the image is filtered.

Comment: For now I'm just making the fixed parent width 33% and the child 300%. See: http://jsfiddle.net/vFYFz/2/